# CSS isn't being applied uniformly across browsers

Tags: apex, visualforce

SETUP:

I have a page  where I'm putting in a lot of fields. The output labels are being rendered on several lines  Here, social security # is going onto 3 lines

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem helpText="hepMe">
    <apex:outputLabel value="Social Security Number" />
    <apex:outputField value="{!obj.Social_Security_Number__c}" />
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

To get around this, I changed the implementation to pageblocksections

```
 <apex:pageBlocksection columns="1">
      <apex:pageBlockSectionItem helpText="help" dataStyle="text-align:left; width: 30%; max-width: 30%;">
           <apex:outputLabel value="Social Security Number" />
           <apex:outputField value="{!Obj.Social_Security_Number__c}" />
      </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
</apex:pageblockSection>
```

PROBLEM:

The CSS `dataStyle="text-align:left; width: 30%; max-width: 30%;"` is not being uniformly applied across browsers. it looks great in IE, but in FF the field columns are not lining up properly.

How do I fix this?

Comment: When you state that 'Social Security Number' is going onto three lines, do you mean that the label has breaks in the text and is displayed one word on each line?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why you need to explicitly write all these tags and can't use only `<apex:outputfield>`? Have you tried applying `!important` in your css? http://stackoverflow.com/a/13823576/313628 Last but not least, can we get a screenshot of the issue? ;)

Comment: I'm wondering why you're using pageBlockSectionItem at all. When you use <apex:outputField/> the label is implicitly included when you place it inside an <apex:pageBlockSection>. Did you go that route because of the formatting problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce renders `pageBlockSections` as tables, and in the example you listed (because the columns attribute is set to `1`) the `pageBlockSectionItem` is a row in the table. Essentially, you're changing the width of a column (using the dataStyle attribute). However, I'm assuming not all of your `pageBlockSectionItems` have their width set in your page.

To fix this, you will need to uniformly apply the css (`dataStyle="text-align:left; width: 30%; max-width: 30%;"`) to all `pageBlockSectionItems`. Instead of applying the css to each tag, I suggest you include the following `style`.

```
<style type="text/css">
  .detailList {
      table-layout: fixed;
  }
  .labelCol {
      text-align: left !important;
      width: 30% !important;
      max-width: 30% !important;
  }
</style>
```

Also note that the `.detailList` and `.labelCol` CSS classes are owned by Salesforce. So, if Salesforce ever changed their CSS structure, or updated their interface, this would likely look very differently or, it may not work. If you'd like to avoid this, you can change the class names and add a `styleClass=".your-class-name"` attribute to each label.

Answer (score 2):

If you are attempting to stop the text from wrapping within the outputLabel, you can use the CSS property `white-space` with a  `nowrap` value to prevent the text from breaking into multiple lines of text.

You could apply this style to the labels using either a native element class that SalesForce renders (i.e. `labelCol`) or add your own `styleClass` attribute to the label to target your own specified elements... or directly on the label using the style attribute.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .noWrap { white-space: nowrap; }
</style>

<apex:outputLabel value="Social Security Number" styleClass="noWrap" />
```

Comment: I'm doing that, but now the column labels are not lining up.

Comment: A screenshot added to your original question along with all of the things that you are doing would be incredibly helpful. Especially since you make no mention of using the nowrap attribute in your original post.

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of dataStyle you must use **dataStyleClass** for pageBlockSectionItems

```
dataStyleClass="text-align:left; width: 30%; max-width: 30%;"
```